# IPython Widgets - Handle many buttons and textboxes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have many rows that contain a textbox and a button each. I would like to change the value of a textbox by pressing a button that belongs to the same row. But I also want to avoid creating a function for each button.

This is what I tried so far:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def mk_btn(description, txt):
    btn = widgets.Button(description=description, layout=ipw.Layout(width="45px"))
    btn.on_click(btn_clicked(btn,txt))
    return btn

def btn_clicked(btn, txt):
    txt.value = "Button Pressed"

txt1 = widgets.Text(value='Button not pressed yet', placeholder='', description='1:', disabled=False)
bt1 = mk_btn('...',txt1)

txt2 = widgets.Text(value='Button not pressed yet', placeholder='', description='2:', disabled=False)
bt2 = mk_btn('...',txt2)

txt3 = widgets.Text(value='Button not pressed yet', placeholder='', description='3:', disabled=False)
bt3 = mk_btn('...',txt3)


row1 = widgets.HBox((txt1, bt1))
row2 = widgets.HBox((txt2, bt2))
row3 = widgets.HBox((txt3, bt3))


col = widgets.VBox((row1, row2, row3))
display(col)
```

When I run the code, all textboxes have value "Button Pressed" even before I press the button.
And when I press the button it returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How can I implement this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: try changing to `btn.on_click(lambda btn=btn, txt=txt : btn_clicked(btn,txt))`